# Flutter: Wrap multiple GridViews

Tags: flutter

In the case of two GridViews where the first has 1 item, and the second has 7 items:

```
// GridView 1
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemCount: 1,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(...)
      },
  ),
// GridView 2
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemCount: 7,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(...)
      },
  ),
```

Is it possible to wrap them so that the layout consists of 4 equal rows (2 items per row)? At the moment, the rows will consist of: 1 item, 2 items, 2 items, 2 items, 1 item.

I know it's possible to combine a list or map into one GridView - but in the case that you needed two separate GridViews (ie, unique styling), is the above possible?

Comment: why aren't you using only one `GridView` with using `crossAxisCount` of 4

Comment: share the expected UI and try to be more brief regarding your requirement.

Comment: Why not using one gridview. Maybe someone here have some solution for that problem.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe he wants to merge two gridview that looks like one.

Comment: then the better solution will be to merge two lists and use the new list with one `GridView` with `crossAxisCount` of 4.

Comment: I'm aware that I can combine Maps/Lists and use them in one GridView, I was just wondering if the above was possible - similar to how you would wrap divs in web design.

Answer (score 2):

you can save both items in List

```
List <dynamic> itemsList = [];
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemCount: itemsList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(...)
          },
      ),
```